# Error: Invalid field Job_Application__r for SObject Position__c

Tags: visualforce, custom-object, relationships

I have two custom objects those are position and job application objects,those are related by lookup relationship.But when try to access the job applications through relationship I m getting above Error.
please help me out.

here is my visualforce Page

```
       <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Position__c.Job_Application__r}" var="JA"></apex:pageBlockTable>

       <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
           <apex:commandButton value="save" action="{!save}"/>
            <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}"/>
       </apex:pageBlockButtons>
   </apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: You probably want `Job_Applications__r`. The name of the relation is set as one of the properties of the lookup field on the child object.

Comment: @Lex, you should add this as an answer as I believe you are correct.  Perhaps show the OP where they can go to find the Child Relationship Name as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use the child relationship name, probably `Job_Applications__r` in this case.

You can find the child relationship name as a part of the properties of the lookup field on the child object. Click on the name of the lookup field, the child relationship name appears at the bottom right of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Error: Invalid field Job_Applications__r for SObject Position__c

```
 function loadApplicants() {
        <apex:repeat value="{!Position__c.Job_Applications__r}" var="jobApp">
            applicants.push({ 
                name: "{!JSENCODE(jobApp.Candidate__r.First_Name__c + ' ' + 
                                 jobApp.Candidate__r.Last_Name__c)}",
                address: "{!JSENCODE(jobApp.Candidate__r.Street__c  + ', ' + 
                                    jobApp.Candidate__r.City__c + ', ' + 
                                    jobApp.Candidate__r.State_Province__c)}",
                viewLink: "{!JSENCODE(LINKTO(jobApp.Candidate__r.First_Name__c + 
                                       ' ' + jobApp.Candidate__r.Last_Name__c, 
                                    $Action.Candidate__c.View, 
                                    jobApp.Candidate__c))}"
            });
        </apex:repeat>
    }
```

Comment: If you have a question you can start a new question bu clicking "Ask question" link on the top right. You shouldn't put your questions as answers for other questions.